# Componentization in Django apps using custom template tags with script tag

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm developing a Django project, comprising of several apps.
I have a base app that contains global stuff, such as CSS, JS, custom template tags (I will call them CTTs from now on), etc.

The thing is, I would like to have some CTTs that include HTML and script tags with JS code (eg. autocomplete inputs, delete button with confirmation modal, etc). My intention here is to have self-contained components to be plugged all across the project.

My concern is if this would be a good practice, as I would not separate JS code in '.js' files and stuff. I tend to think that this would be ok, as the behaviour provided by JS code would be in a certain way incapsulated in the CTTs.

Would like to hear opinions about this =)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at Wagtail! ;)
https://wagtail.org/
(the streamfield is where it gets interesting)
https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/topics/streamfield.html
Doing this with templatetags can get tedious, with wagtail you could build your own components - it'll also provide you some real world knowledge as companies like changes on their sites with no downtime.

*A CMS is a near requirement for most websites.*

But ultimately as always, the answer is ***it depends***.
If you do not require customisability, templatetags can be a great option.
There are some libraries which can provide most of the functionality you're looking for. https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/templatetags/

`django_compressor` might help with some staticfile problems, as it can compress all of your js and css files into a single css or js file.
This gives you some leniency on what you can include, as you will not have to load in possibly 100's of different scripts client side, but can still separate all files easily on the backend side of things. This does tend to make the file a bit bigger, but people most people have decent internet nowadays.
This also means that you don't have any/many loose script tags in the html, which reduces context switching on the browser and tends to increase performance.